# WebGL - WWW doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm having an issue with using WWW and WWWForm when building for WebGL.

I have a script that basically connects to a php page on my site and uses wwwform to pass in the username and password. The page echos back whether the password is correct or not, and unity reads `www.text` to determine the outcome. On the WebGL version of the game however, `www.text` returns nothing as I believe it is being called as relative path from the directory of the game. Here's my code:

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("usernameField", uid);
    form.AddField("passwordField", pwd);

    WWW www = new WWW(loginURL, form);
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log(www.text);
```

Keep it mind that it works fine as an application but only gets the issue on WebGL in another directory from the login.php file.

Any ideas how I can make the path absolute rather than reltive?

Thanks

Comment: Check if there is an error with `Debug.Log(www.error);`. You can edit your question with this error.

Comment: Ok will do tomorrow morning

Comment: Ok I got "Unknown Error", which is very unhelpful. Also, one of my friends managed to get into it but I can't seem to do it. He used my account and everything...very confusing...

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED - My server needed to enable CORS (cross origin resource sharing) which I achieved by adding the following headers to my .htaccess file:

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept, X-Access-Token, X-Application-Name, X-Request-Sent-Time"